# How can i clear the typeahead input with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, typeahead

The html part in my test case is

```
    <div class="typeahead__container">
         <div class="typeahead__field">
             <div class="typeahead__query">
                  <input class="txtSearchProduct" id="txtSearchProduct" autocomplete="off" tabindex="8">
                  </div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

While using this [jquery typeahad](https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead) library,
like so... ([demo's here)](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/)

```
$.typeahead({
            input: '.txtSearchProduct',
            minLength: 0,
            maxItem: 15,
            order: "asc",
            hint: true,
            href: "",
            searchOnFocus: true,
            emptyTemplate: 'No results found "{{query}}"',
            display: ["id", "code", "name", "table"],
            template: "{{name}}<small style='color:#999;'>{{code}}</small>",
            source: {
                "Products": {
                    ajax: {
                        url: "/search/product",
                        path: ""
                    }
                }
            },
            callback: {
                onClickAfter: function (node, a, item, event) {
                    //debugger;
                    event.preventDefault;
                    //$("#txtSearchProduct").val("");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/controller/add/" + item.id,
                        success: function (data) {

                        },
                        error: function (data) {

                        },
                        done: function () {

                            $("#loading").hide();

                        }

                    });
                }
            },

            debug: true
        });
```

I have issues in clearing the input after selection.

On the callback event i tried to clear the value by using

```
$('#txtSearchProduct').typeahead('val', '');
```

or even with

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead('txtSearchProduct', '');
```

but any of these works as expected. It seems that the event that was raised upon selecting the input, does not raise any more.

**Update**
While using `$("#txtSearchProduct").val("")` the input is cleared, but again it partially works unless i click on the close button.

[image]

Comment: Would you not just clear the input?  `$("#txtSearchProduct").val("")` ?

Comment: Could you please check the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: after reading the documentation more carefully I've found:

> *Triggering manual `Typeahead` events*
>
> Each of the `Typeahead` events can be controlled by script and not only by user interaction. **They all require a set of condition to be executed.** The exact conditions can be tracked down inside the delegateEvents() function.
>
> ```
> // Events
> 'focus.typeahead',
> 'input.typeahead',
> 'propertychange.typeahead',
> 'keydown.typeahead',
> 'dynamic.typeahead',
> 'generateOnLoad.typeahead'
>
> // Trigger a manual search from the string inside the input
> // See #Game_v3 demo to understand why it is being used at that place
> $('#mySearchInput').trigger('input.typeahead');
> ```

The documentation is not thorough. There is nothing about `propertychange.typeahead` event except for its name, and about "set of condition to be executed". So I still can't say with a 100% certainty, but this also should work (works on the demo page):

```
$("#txtSearchProduct").val("")
$("#txtSearchProduct").trigger('propertychange.typeahead');
```

And it doesn't break encapsulation.

---

**Original answer:**
I don't see anything about your case in the documentation. But in the source code of *Typeahead* you can see this:

```js
$("<span/>", {
    class: this.options.selector.cancelButton,
    html: "×",
    mousedown: function (e) {
       // Don't blur the input
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       e.preventDefault();

       scope.resetInput();
       scope.node.trigger("input" + scope.namespace, [e]);
    }
}).insertBefore(this.node);
```

where `scope` is `Typeahead` object for the input.
So, I tried this:

```js
const typeahead_for_input = window.Typeahead[".js-typeahead-country_v1"]

typeahead_for_input.resetInput()
    // clears input and reset some internal variabales

typeahead_for_input.node.trigger("input" + typeahead_for_input.namespace, []) // no event
    // Hides "cancel" button, and maybe a lot more - haven't looked into
```

in the browser console on the [demo](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/) page, and it worked fine, as far as I could notice. In your case you should access `Typeahead` object of your input with this:

```js
const typeahead_for_input = window.Typeahead[".txtSearchProduct"]
```

Of cause, this approach breaks encapsulation. But either this or you should ask for a feature from the authors off *Typeahead* and wait. Because just clearing the input value is not enough - you need to correctly clear the state of a `Typeahead` object.

**Another way:** or you can just simulate keyboard events. Set focus on the input and send one `<Esc>`, that should do it.

Comment: $("#txtSearchProduct").trigger('propertychange.typeahead'); did the trick! That is great, thanks!